# How to get rid of "Argument 'context' might be null" in Toast warning

Tags: java, android

Am trying to use a Toast in a non-activity class. To do this, am trying the following:

```
//Method to get all books from database
public List<Book> getAllBooks() {
    List<Book> books = new LinkedList<Book>();
    Context context = null;
    // 1. build the query
    String query = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_BOOKS;

    // 2. get reference to writable DB
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

    // 3. go over each row, build book and add it to list
    Book book = null;
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            book = new Book();
            book.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            book.setTitle(cursor.getString(1));
            book.setAuthor(cursor.getString(2));

            // Add book to books
            books.add(book);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(context, "No books in database", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    ....
```

but `context` has a yellow warning mark on it saying `Argument 'context' might be null`

which is expected since it's initialized to null. How do i use the context in this situation without my program crashing? This method is called from the `onCreate()` method of an activity. I need to display this message.

Comment: Consider not doing UI work like `Toast` in a non-UI class like this. The caller can have a toast like this in case the returned list is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call `getAllBooks` from `onCreate` of an activity, you can simply pass the activity instance to serve as the context.

```
public List<Book> getAllBooks(Context context) {
    ....
}
```

In the activity class :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    ... getAllBooks(this); ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course, the 'context' might be null. It IS null, as you initialize it with null in "Context context = null" line of your code. For a Toast it is usually well enough to initialize it with "= getApplicationContext()" or to do as Eran proposed.